# What's the best option for connecting to a database via JDBC using .NET?

Tags: database, jdbc, driver, drivers, jdbc-odbc

I may be looking for the equivalent of the JDBC-ODBC bridge with the inverse behaviour so that an ODBC query, for example, is translated into a corresponding JDBC query. Does such a thing even exist?

There are several hundred JDBC connection strings that require validation and I need to be able to execute queries using these connection strings. I cannot replace them because other applications depend on them.

What are the options in this unenviable space?

Comment: JDBC is an API, and a Java-specific one at that.  There's no such thing as a "JDBC query", the API implementation is specific to the database protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I would just query the db directly using the ADO.NET technology of your choice (ADO.NET itself, Entity Framework, NHibernate, whatever).  Why do you need to talk to JDBC at all?

UPDATE

It's not ideal, but you could create your data access layer in J# (Java eq. in .NET, but it's not been maintained through current framework version).

You could also try IKVM (http://www.ikvm.net/)

I don't know of any other options that are easy.

Comment: All I have are hundreds of JDBC connection strings and they need to be maintained as such because other applications depend on them.